# Xamarin.Forms reproduciendo audio

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, audio-manager, mp3

hola amigos estoy tratando de reproducir un mp3 para las notificaciones de un App que desarrollo en **Xamarin.Forms** Estuve leyendo al respecto y muy similar a **SQLite** debo manejar este suceso con una interfaz, pero tengo problemas para referenciarlo

> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Pienso que quizá es la forma en la que trato de reproducirlo,

Trato de ejecutar mi método de reproducir desde esta clase

```js
public class AudioService
    {
        //private IAudio awx;

        public void Play() {
            DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().PlayAudioFile("beep.mp3");

        }
    }
```

```js
// Interfáz

 public interface IAudio
    {
        void PlayAudioFile(string fileName);
    }
```

Esta es mi clase handler de **Android**, engo mi archivo beep en la carpeta de **Assets**

```js
public class AudioService: IAudio {
  public AudioService() {}

  public void PlayAudioFile(string fileName) {
    var player = new MediaPlayer();
    var fd = global::Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd(fileName);
    player.Prepared += (s, e) => {
      player.Start();
    };
    player.SetDataSource(fd.FileDescriptor, fd.StartOffset, fd.Length);
    player.Prepare();
  }
}
```

Alguien sabe algo al respecto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente te faltó añadir:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(AudioService))]
```

antes de la definición del namespace en la clase AudioService de Android.

Comment: yo hice todo igual como lo planteas y me marca el siguiente error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\Dmorales\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ProyAppPortatil\81\res Pegue el archivo mp3 en el proyecto android en la carpeta essets y ahora me sale el siguiente error: Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: beep-05.mp3. Que puedo estar haciendo mal. Saludos.